# PC turns on, but Monitor doesn't detect any signal. Keyboard and mouse also not powered

Tags: hardware-failure

Specs:
Power: Corsair VS 550 watts
Motherboard: B450 Aorus M
CPU: Amd ryzen 5
GPU: Amd radeon rx 570 (Sapphire pulse)
RAM: 1 x Hyper X DDR3 8gb memory

When I press the power button, the usual happens, lights turn on and I can hear the silent hum of the pc but then my Monitor shows a "No Signal Error" and then just stays blank. I also notice connected devices like the keyboard and mouse are not powered on.

I opened it up and checked if anything was loose, but everything was secured in its proper place. The cpu, ram and gpu were all intact, and I haven't gotten any beep codes from my pc.

All cables are properly connected, the power supply, usb mouse, ps2 keyboard and hdmi cables.

Please help, I cannot find the problem and it's driving me crazy. Any help is much appreciated

Comment: This is too broad to resolve without more information, e.g. *when* did the issue occur?

Comment: Remove all RAM purposely and start, if CPU is good you should hear beep codes (Assuming speaker is connected to the board). Then Re-Seat the RAM an try again. Disconnect all other devices like HDD, DVD etc if any. First try to operate with bare minimum components. If Ryzen CPU is GPU, then first try with its Graphics out from mobo itself rather than attempting to install RX570. Try RAM in another slot.

Comment: @DrMoishe Pippik I was using my pc normally, then I shut it down (nothing strange happened). Took a break for a few minutes and when I went back, monitor doesn't detect it and keyboard and mouse are not powered.          This happened yesterday morning

Comment: In addition to what patkim said, try removing the 24-pin power connector from the motherboard and then reconnecting it.  I've seen that work on a few occasions with this type of issue.